# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and governance registry configuration

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-esb

I have one server running the ESB and another running the governance registry.

I am using the embedded h2 database.  I can't connect the ESB to the Registry.
I get the following error

SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL

The jar with the the driver is in the path and works with a local h2 instance.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be due to the h2 database not being able to accept multiple connections. But you need to provide more details to answer this question? Perhaps the entire stack trace. Usually, when we work with remote registries we use mysql or similar as the DB.

Since the h2 driver is shipped and it's already in the classpath anyway, it can't be due to a problem with the h2 driver, unless you changed the driver.